# How to handle the WebSocket connection in low bandwidth in android

Tags: android, performance, websocket, android-webview, okhttp

I am facing an issue in low network(below 1Mbps) , I am loading a PPT in a webView using the webSocket , now in good bandwidth the PPT gets loaded perfectly but on low bandwidth in Kbps, the webSocket is throwing failure message as **"Expected HTTP 101 response but was '400 Bad Request'"** and also gets Disconnected, how can make the webSocket not being disconnected even in low network range